# React chip input field

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm using React 17 and tried to use different chip input fields like material-ui-chip-input etc. Unfortunately, all npm packages I tried do not work with react version 17.

Do you know of any component that works with this version or how I could create one myself?

Thanks in advance

Edit:
I have managed to do what I wanted, but unfortunately, I now get the following error when pressing enter / adding a new item:

> index.js:1 Warning: Cannot update a component (`CreatePoll`) while rendering a different component (`ForwardRef(Autocomplete)`)

Here is the codesandbox which shows the problem:
https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-greider-wr9wq?file=/src/App.tsx

Comment: I have used this some time back on mui v4, check this [lab component](https://v4.mui.com/components/autocomplete/#multiple-values) and [mui core](https://mui.com/components/autocomplete/)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[image]

why don't you use this instead of a new package?
Autocomplete exactly do that.

```
const [receivers, setReceivers] = React.useState<string[]>([]);


    import Autocomplete from '@mui/material/Autocomplete';
         <Autocomplete
            multiple
            onChange={(e, value) => setReceivers((state) => value)}
            id="tags-filled"
            options={top100Films.map((option) => option.title)}
            defaultValue={[top100Films[13].title]}
            freeSolo
            renderTags={(value, getTagProps) =>
              value.map((option, index) => (
                <Chip variant="outlined" label={option} {...getTagProps({ index })} />
              ))
            }
            renderInput={(params) => (
              <TextField
                {...params}
                variant="filled"
                label="freeSolo"
                placeholder="Favorites"
              />
            )}
          />
```

Comment: isn't the autocomplete used if you have predefined options? I do not have available options, I want to be able to freely add values

Comment: Ohh sorry I thought it might help

Comment: Oh I think it actually did help me! Now I'm just wondering how new items can get added to the array (in your example top100Films)

Comment: https://mui.com/components/autocomplete/

Comment: I added a picture in my answer

Comment: thanks I've looked at the link but can't seem to find the answer how a new value that is inputted in the TextFields gets added to the array

Comment: I have edited my question and added a codeandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-greider-wr9wq?file=/src/App.tsx could you maybe take a look why the error in the console happens?

Comment: you use setState in a wrong way

Comment: I changed your code here https://codesandbox.io/s/long-morning-oubt4?file=/src/App.tsx

Comment: you need to use onChange. Good luck :)))

Comment: @Samira it does not work if you have multiple inputs inside a `map` though

Comment: @RamonDias did you change the id ? or did you use different states? if you need more help please add a code sandbox. it really helps us to find the bug.

Comment: @Samira thanks for your help! The thing is that I was passing something like `key={Math.random()}` for each component, which is not the correct way to use the `key` prop. Following [this lead](https://react.dev/learn/rendering-lists#rules-of-keys) it worked like a charm! Thanks again :)

Answer (score 2):

```
import React from 'react'
import { MuiChipsInput } from 'mui-chips-input'

const MyComponent = () => {
  const [chips, setChips] = React.useState([])

  const handleChange = (newChips) => {
    setChips(newChips)
  }

  return (
    <MuiChipsInput value={chips} onChange={handleChange} />
  )
}
```

Source:
https://github.com/viclafouch/mui-chips-input

*Supports both React 17 / 18 and MUI V5*

Answer (score 2):

Use the `freeSolo` prop of `Autocomplete`, and just set the `options` prop to an empty array:

```
 <Autocomplete
    multiple
    freeSolo
    value={value}
    options={[]}
    renderTags={(value, getTagProps) =>
      value.map((option, index) => (
        <Chip label={option} {...getTagProps({ index })} onDelete={()=> /* remove option from value array */} />
      ))
    }
    renderInput={params => (
      <TextField
        {...params}
        variant="outlined"
        label="Add Chip"
        placeholder="Type and press enter"
      />
    )}
  />
```

Comment: Great approach, simple and not relying on outside libs